# What is the procedure to email the test score of a test conducted on google forms?

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have created a test through google form, and I want to send the score result to the participants. I have created a copy of the response and put scoring through `if` functions.  And then in the next worksheet, I have summed the score. Now I want to send that calculated score to the participants. I have entered the script in the script editor and set trigger on form submit but I am getting errors.

Would the error be because the script takes the default sheet and not the one where I have created score function?  If so, how do I change that?

Here is the code that I used:

```
function myFunction(e)
{
    var userName = e.values[1];
    var userEmail = e.values[2];
    var score = e.values[3];
    var subject = "Thank you for your participation: Find your Score";
    var message = "Thank you, " + userName + " for choosing to participate in this test. Your score is " + score;
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: Here is the code that I used 

function myFunction(e){

var userName = e.values[1];
var userEmail = e.values[2];
var score = e.values[3];
var subject = "Thank you for your participation: Find your Score";
var message = "Thank you, " + userName + " for choosing to participate in   this test. Your score is " +score;
MailApp.sendEmail (userEmail, subject, message);}

Comment: I have created a test and I want to send the score result to the participants. I have created copy of response and put scoring through if functions. And then in the next worksheet, I have summed the score. Now I want to use that calculated score to be sent to the participants. I have entered the script in the script editor and set trigger on form submit but I am getting errors.

would the error be because the script take the default sheet and not the one wher i have created score function. How do I change that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. Send an e-mail from the form or send a notification from the result collection spreadsheet (limited to spreadsheet collaborators).

For the first, you have to use the script editor found under tools. There are several examples to get you started. I'd recommend you take a look at: http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-confirmation-emails/28386/

For the second, you use the notifications option, see: https://www.maketecheasier.com/send-email-notifications-google-forms/

Comment: the 2nd option does not apply to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code that I used 

function myFunction(e){

var userName = e.values[1];
var userEmail = e.values[2];
var score = e.values[3];
var subject = "Thank you for your participation: Find your Score";
var message = "Thank you, " + userName + " for choosing to participate in   this test. Your score is " +score;
MailApp.sendEmail (userEmail, subject, message);}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Start Function Error Message Trigger End
11/16/17 10:23 AM myFunction TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. (line 32, file "Code") formSubmit 11/16/17 10:23 AM

The above is the error I have received when using the code you have provided.